# Passing one compoenent to another out of json data

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a slide carousel in react and I want to be able to have slide components listed in a json file that I parse out and send to a parent component for rendering. I can see it can be done by passing the component, but I'm unsure how to parse it out of json from string to actual component.

My json is like this:

```
{ "slides":
[
 {
  "id": "slide0",
  "title": "Slide: 0",
  "caption": "Slide caption: 0",
  "slideNum": 0,
  "url": "adminLogins",
  "slideType": "<AdminLoginsChart />"
},
...etc. json
]}
```

I can pass the  component to another component like this:

```
<Slide component={this.state.slides[this.state.slideNum].slideType}/>
```

but when I bring the component in as a string in json, I can't seem to turn it back into a component to pass. Replacing the quotes with nothing doesn't work and doing a JSON.parse(item) gives me a json parse error. Has anybody tried passing string values as components and somehow transform them into components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close! If you need it to be in a JSON file (so a string), then try this:

```
import YourComponent from './YourComponent';    

{
  slides: [{
    id: 'slide0',
    title: 'Slide 0',
    ...
    slideType: 'YourComponent',
  }],
}
```

Then, in `<Slide />`'s render you'd do something like this:

```
const components = [{ 'YourComponent': YourComponentReference }];

const Slide = ({
  component,
} => {
  const Component = components[component];
  return (
    <Component />
  );
});
```

Comment: This isn't working for me either. I need the YourComponent to be in a string representation to be in the json file. But even when I manually put it in state without quotes, it does't pull the component.

Comment: Here is an example jsfiddle using your method. See anything wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me using a fiddle. Here I am trying to pull one component from another here like you've shown: https://jsfiddle.net/bradrice/69z2wepo/86971/ forget the path issues

Comment: I updated the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/87026/, seems to be working now. Taking it a step further you can see https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/87027/ which uses a string to grab a component type

Answer (score 1):

Provided your components are stored in the same folder as the Slide component, the javascript files are capitalized (e.g. AdminLoginsChart.js), and the the name of the component is available in your JSON file (e.g. "slideType": "AdminLoginsChart"), you can then write your Slide component in this way:

```
class Slide extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { component, ...props } = this.props;
    const Component = require(`./${component}`).default;
    return (
      <div className="slide>
        <Component {...props} />
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

If you file name is using underscore instead, you could use the [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) `snakeCase` function to convert the component name to a file name.

Comment: I'm trying but getting this error: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Comment: You need to adapt my example to your own situation e.g. if the component's file name is lowercase separated with dashes, you would need to convert from the component name form, e.g. AdminLoginsChart to admin-logins-chart.

Comment: Sorry, I was declaring a `component` variable but was then using `componentName` instead on the following line ... FIXED!

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me using a fiddle. Here I am trying to pull one component from another here like you've shown: jsfiddle.net/bradrice/69z2wepo/86971 forget the path issues